# Validators keep going even if bad input

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm building server-side validation using regex in the following format:

```
protected void valMessage_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    regex = new Regex(@"^\d+$");

    if (regex.Match(args.Value).Success == true)
        args.IsValid = true;
    else
        args.IsValid = false;
}
```

This is connected to a custom validator. The problem is that even when it fails (i.e. when `args.IsValid = false;`) the page still keeps going normally. Shouldn't it stop as soon as it finds a control with `IsValid = false`? Why is mine running the code nonetheless?

Comment: You know there is a RegularExpressionValidator that does this for you?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what you mean by the "page keeps running" it is hard to say. Presuming that you have an event handler responding to clicks on a "submit" button, you should check Page.IsValid inside the event handler.

Another mistake I often make is forgetting to set the ValidationGroup on both the button and all of my validators.

Comment: Oh i need to check manually? I tought asp.net checks if the page is valid automatically. At lest it did with all the other validatiors.

Comment: Well, ever article on validators recommend checking Page.IsValid anyways, probably in case javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check in Page_Load event with Page.IsValid(). 
2.You can fire the validation with Page.Validate(). Is your server side validation fires? 
3. If answer of step 2 is no  then please verify

1. Custom validator's OnServerValidate property you have set the correct sever validation function.

   1. You have set up corrent validation group to Custom Validator.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an expert in ASP.Net....you should go through Validation Controls once and nearly all the validations are done there itself...

```
RequiredField Validator
Compare Validator
RegularExpression Validator
Range Validator
Custom Validator
Validation Summary
```

You can get a brief description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp). Hope it helps.